# javascript hacks using cross site scripting - where is the injection of code posted to

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new coder doing a web security tutorial that looks at javascript hacks using cross site scripting in a rails project.

In my project, I have injected a piece of malicious javascript into the user_first_name input field on our account_settings.html.erb which in turn generates a dialogue box to say that you have been hacked every time you refresh or visit a new page. (Please see screenshots)

Problem: the lecturer has finished without explaining how to clear this rogue code from our project and I can't get shot of the annoying dialogue box.

I can see the XSS code in the view page source but I am having difficult finding it in my project in the views nor can I source it using the command T function in sublime.

I am not seeking security advice, merely steering as to where this injection of XSS code can be found within my project or is posted to so that I may clear it.

[image]
[image]

> new.html.erb

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">

        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span4 offset4">
            <div class="signup">
      <%= form_for @user, :html => {:id => "account_edit", :class=> "signup-wrapper"} do |f| %>

          <div class="header">
                    <h2>Sign Up</h2>
                    <p>Fill out the form below to login</p>
                  </div>

          <div class="content">
                <%= f.text_field :email, {:class => "input input-block-level", :placeholder => "Email"} %>

                <%= f.text_field :first_name, {:class => "input input-block-level", :placeholder => "First Name"} %>

                <%= f.text_field :last_name, {:class => "input input-block-level", :placeholder => "Last Name"} %>

                  <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.password_field :password, {:class => "input input-block-level", :placeholder => "Password"}%>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, {:class => "input input-block-level", :placeholder => "Confirm Password"}%>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Submit", {:id => 'submit_button', :class => "btn btn-info btn-large pull-right"} %>
          </div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <% end %>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

> account_settings.html.erb

```
<div class="dashboard-wrapper">
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <div id="success" style="display: none;" class="alert alert-block alert-success fade in">
                <h4 class="alert-heading">
                  Success!
                </h4>
                <p>
                  Information successfully updated.
                </p>
              </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span12">
        <div id="failure" style="display: none;" class="alert alert-block alert-error fade in">
                    <h4 class="alert-heading">
                      Error!
                    </h4>
                    <p>
                      Failed to update.
                    </p>
                  </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
          <div class="widget">
            <div class="widget-header">
              <div class="title">
                <span class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe090;"></span> Profile Settings
                <span class="mini-title">
                  Edit your account details
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="widget-body">
           <%= form_for @user, :html => {:id => "account_edit"} do |f|%>
               <%= f.hidden_field :user_id%>
          <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.label :email, nil, {:class => "control-label"}%>
            <%= f.text_field :email, {:class => "span12"}%>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
            <%= f.label :first_name, nil, {:class => "control-label"}%>
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, {:class => "span12"} %>
          </div>

          <div>
            <%= f.label :last_name, nil, {:class => "control-label"}%>
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, {:class => "span12"} %>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
            <%= f.label :password, nil, {:class => "control-label"}%>
            <%= f.password_field :password, {:class => "span12", :placeholder => "Enter Password"}%>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
              <%= f.label :password_confirmation, nil, {:class => "control-label"}%>
              <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, {:class => "span12", :placeholder => "Enter Password"} %>
            </div>

          <div class="form-actions no-margin">
            <%= f.submit "Submit", {:id => 'submit_button', :class => "btn btn-info pull-right"} %>
          </div>

          <div class="clearfix">
                </div>
           <% end %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<%= javascript_include_tag ('validation.js')%>

<script type="text/javascript">

$("#submit_button").click(function(event) {
    var valuesToSubmit = $("#account_edit").serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: <%= "/users/#{current_user.user_id}.json".inspect.html_safe %>,
    data: valuesToSubmit,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(response) {
    if (response.msg == "failure") {
      $('#failure').show(500).delay(1500).fadeOut();
    } else {
      $('#success').show(500).delay(1500).fadeOut();
    }
    },
    error: function(event) {
    $('#failure').show(500).delay(1500).fadeOut();
    }
  });
});

</script>
```

> _header.html.erb

```
<header>
    <span style="color:#eee;margin-left:10px;">
     Font Size:
     <a href="<%= home_dashboard_index_path %>?font=8pt" style="font-size:10pt;color:#eee;">A</a>
     <a href="<%= home_dashboard_index_path %>?font=200%25" style="font-size:18pt;color:#eee;">A</a>
   </span>
     <div class="user-profile">
       <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
         <img src=" <%= image_path('profile_color.jpg')%>"  alt="profile">

       </a>
       <span class="caret"></span>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
         <li>
      <%= link_to "account settings", user_account_settings_path(:user_id => current_user.user_id) %>
         </li>
         <li>
           <%= link_to "logout", logout_path %>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
     <ul class="mini-nav">
     <li style="color: #FFFFFF">
    <!--
    I'm going to use HTML safe because we had some weird stuff
    going on with funny chars and jquery, plus it says safe so I'm guessing
    nothing bad will happen
    -->
    Welcome, <%= current_user.first_name.html_safe %>

     </li>
     </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: `<%= current_user.first_name.html_safe %>` why you need the `html_safe` method here? if you remove this method then xss is not possible.

Comment: I don't need that in their and understand that it is counter productive, the lecturer told us that at the start, I'm looking to find where the injection now resides in my project

Comment: _where the injection now resides in my project_ - here `<%= current_user.first_name.html_safe %>`

Comment: I know the html safe makes my code vulnerable, it is a demo project and html safe has been placed deliberate to show us, what I want to know us, where is that code now in my project

Comment: I can't get what you need. It's unclear for me what you asking.

Comment: How do I get rid of the XSS code which has been injected into the form class.

Comment: stop using `.html_safe` on the dangerous user output.

Comment: ok and and soon as i delete the .html_safe the system will stop showing the XSS dialogue box

Comment: also you can use the `sanitize` helper `<%= sanitize current_user.first_name.html_safe %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you saved it, run rake db:reset (THIS WILL RESET THE DB AND CLEAR ALL ENTERS)
or
If you want to save entries go to command line of your rails project and type 'rails c' 
'x = database_name.find_by(id_of_entery)'
'x.destroy'

here is a cool rails console guide https://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2014/3/11/console-shortcuts-tips-tricks

Comment: thank you very much for understanding what I was asking and providing a coherent answer.